# how to use method ax.set() in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Some codes like

```
ax.set_xlabel('abc')
```

can be transformed into

```
props={
'xlabel': 'abc',
}
ax.set(props)
```

So how to use ax.set() to rewrite

```
ax.set_xlabel('abc', fontsize=20)
```

or something like this, or it just doesn't work.